# Selenium explicit wait with relative XPath locator

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver with Python 3.4.

I'm writing a scraper, and locating elements using XPaths relative to some non-root ancestor element, such as below:

```
ancestor_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(ancestor_xpath)
child_element = ancestor_element.find_element_by_xpath(child_xpath)
```

This works as expected. However, I am unsure how to do this relative location with an explicit wait call, as the examples I have seen use this syntax:

```
child_element =  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, child_xpath))
)
```

which appears to evaluate the XPath against the page root, and throws an error complaining about the ".//" beginning of the XPath string.

Any advice on this?

Comment: The `wait` [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) includes an example that appears to use a parent element to find its child as opposed to searching from page root. `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_id(“someId”))`. I have not tried it, but merely knew it existed.You should be able to change the query to search by xpath.

Comment: why not combine xpaths and search for child element right away? E.g. if ancestor xpath is `//a/b` and child xpath is `.//c/d`, then it will be same as `//a/b//c/d`

Comment: Another option is to write a custom wait condition: `class child_is_present def __init__(self, ancestor_xpath, child_xpath)... def __call__(self, driver): ancestor_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(*self.ancestor_xpath) child_element = ancestor_element.find_element_by_xpath(*self.child_xpath) if(child_element) return true`

Comment: @RonNorris - The lambda solution is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @KirilS. - Combining the xpaths would definitely be a good solution, but there are many instances of the ancestor element in the page, and I'm passing them in one at a time to this helper method. Meaning combining the xpaths would return the child of every ancestor on the page when I just want the child of one of those ancestors. (e.g. I want only guy #1's name, but I'm getting the names of every guy on the page). I could append a [position()] to the parent XPath to solve this, but the lambda worked out. Anyway, thanks to both of you! I would upvote but seems I'm still too low reputation

Answer (score 2):

Had this same question and follow the `lambda` example from @Ron Norris's comment. However, the documentation isn't clear about how you can find the `child_element` relative to the `ancestor_element`, even when using `lambda`.

You can actually replace `driver` in the `WebDriverWait` call with your `ancestor_element`, to explicitly only search things "under" the `ancestor_element` (even though the docstring states that it has to be an instance of `WebDriver`, I found that a `WebElement` also works).

So I wound up with something like:

```
child_element =  WebDriverWait(ancestor_element,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, child_xpath))
)
```

If you want to use a `lambda`, you could then do:

```
child_element =  WebDriverWait(ancestor_element,10).until(
    lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath(child_xpath)
)
```

Comment: Thanks! `WebDriverWait(child_element, 10)...` is really works whats surprised me